# Binding Page with ViewModel (MVVM) on Universal Windows App

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, uwp

I need to bind a page on Frame control in Xaml wpf page.
my xaml page:

```
<Page
x:Class="MyPro.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MyPro"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:viewmodel="using:MyPro.ViewModel"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:x1="using:System"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Page.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:PagerViewModel x:Name="PagerViewModel"></viewmodel:PagerViewModel>
</Page.DataContext>
<Frame 
       VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
       HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
       Name="frameMainPage"
       DataContext="{Binding Source=Pager.Page, Mode=TwoWay}">        
</Frame>
```

I've tried to use this (but i don't know if it's correct):

> DataContext="{Binding Source=Pager.Page, Mode=TwoWay}"

but doesn't work.

My view model, i call Pager to set the new Page:

```
class PagerViewModel
{
    public PagerViewModel()
    {
        m_pager = new Pager();
    }

    public static Pager m_pager;  
    public Pager Pager
    {
        get
        {
            return m_pager;
        }
        set
        {
            m_pager = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and my model, i set page mode like this:

```
public class Pager : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Page m_page;
    public Page Page
    {
        get
        {
            return m_page;
        }
        set
        {
            m_page = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Page");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I need to change page like this from every part in the code:

```
PagerViewModel.m_pager.Page = new MyPage();
```

How can I do this on Universal windows app UWP?

Comment: Do you not need the `OnPropertyChanged` on `Pager`?

Comment: I haven't tested it yet but wouldn't it be better to bind the `content` property of the frame instead of the `datacontext`property?

Comment: I don't know if better bind content or datacontext, i need a solution and i open to all ideas. But i know that, if i bind content...on the i view i find Pager.page in String format, with white background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved like this:

```
DataContext="{Binding Path=Pager.Page, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

You have to use Path and not Source in Universal App on UWP

Answer (score 1):

Binding to `DataContext` of `Frame` does not do anything. `DataContext` is basically only telling the control what do its binding's relative paths refer to, but don't cause any behavior (or at least this holds for the built-in controls).

In your case you need to bind to the `Content` property of the `Frame` control:

```
<Frame Content="{Binding Pager.Page}" />
```

This does work for me, I have tested it on a blank solution with your code and an additional button on the main page:

**XAML**

```
<Page
    x:Class="App4.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App4"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.DataContext>
        <local:PagerViewModel x:Name="PagerViewModel"></local:PagerViewModel>
    </Page.DataContext>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Frame Width="500" Height="500" Content="{Binding Pager.Page}" />
        <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">Click</Button>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Code-behind**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((PagerViewModel)DataContext).Pager.Page = new SecondPage();
    }
}
```

`SecondPage` is an empty page which I set to have a blue background to be able to clearly see that it is displayed in the `Frame`.